# Show that $\left|\int^{b}_{a}cos(f(x))dx\right| \leq \frac{2}{m}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ has a derivative which is monotonically decreasing and satisfies $f'(x) \geq m > 0, \forall x \in [a,b].$ Then,$\left|\int^{b}_{a}\cos(f(x))\right| \leq \frac{2}{m}$

My attempt: By Bonnett's form of Mean value theorem, $\exists c \in [a,b]$ such that $$\left|\int^{b}_{a}\cos(f(x))dx\right|\leq \int^{b}_{a}\frac{|\cos(f(x))|}{f'(x)}f'(x)dx = f'(a)\int^{c}_{a}\frac{|\cos(f(x))|}{f'(x)}dx \leq \frac{f'(a)}{m}(b-a).$$

Could anyone advise me on how to get the required inequality? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\left| \int_a^b \cos f(x)\, dx \right| \leq \int_a^b \frac{|\cos f(x)| f'(x)}{f'(x)}dx \leq \frac{1}{m} \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} |\cos u| du
$$
and now it should be easy to conclude. Roughly speaking, the last integral is something like $\sin f(b)-\sin f(a)$ and you can estimate this difference from above by $2$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think the computation of  $\int |cos u|$ might be tad laborious.  Anyways, I have gotten it:)